# How can I show a minimum linked to a filter in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

1. I have a scatter plot.
2. I have several groups.
3. I have a cost per product (several products are composing a group)
4. I want the minimal cost per group plot on the scatter.

BUT a data limiting such as `[cost]=Min([cost]) over ([group])` is not respecting the filtering scheme.

Thus I want to be able to filter on these products, the scatter should then be able to display the minimal cost per group respecting the filtering scheme.
This last point (respecting the filtering scheme) is a blocking point on my side. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I don't understand, Limit data by expression and Filtering scheme do not usually block one another. Can you add more specifics?

Comment: The Limit data by expression is applied on the whole dataset and not on the subset after filtering. 
Thus the min(cost) is computed on the complete dataset (using over function) and not on the duvet after filtering

Answer (score 0):

To do the trick, I just created a R function where my input and my output are the whole table BUT using the filtering scheme, meaning that my output is filtered based on this filtering scheme.
Thus, when I apply my data limiting on my scatter plot (using the output of the function), the `min([cost])` is the real one !